# Cross Platform ECDH encryption and Decryption Java and c#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, public-key, diffie-hellman

I am not expert in encryption. We have requirement to encrypt the data in c# and decrypt the same in java. We were able to encrypt and decrypt the data for same key in c# and java. When we try to encrypt the string in c# and decrypt the same in java we are getting

**com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException: AES/GCM/NoPadding decryption failed: Tag mismatch!**

Can some one please help.

Below is the code C# code to encrypt data.

**Code to Decrypt string in C#**

```
public class JWK
    {
        public string alg { get; set; }
        public int? created_at { get; set; }
        public string crv { get; set; }
        public int? expired_at { get; set; }
        public string kid { get; set; }
        public string kty { get; set; }
        public string use { get; set; }
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string d { get; set; }
    }

public static  string stringkey = @" {
            ""y"": ""AGum7Ok3MsKuMfrGtYUoeRq09oXwuO5yiMcxDjPbZglLKaZK-Z_kGt3ZcakVavLx46ieXw4agldm9qV6KmBCf6d7"",
            ""kty"": ""EC"",
            ""d"": ""AaDyXhcUwH90OvzbYJvocSl7uYlZNRZvgj8yesGjtqUWfxmN50NIFfnBpKohNc3wkYqviScjevczATzibw0Cnlgp"",
            ""kty"": ""EC"",
            ""crv"": ""P-521"",
            ""x"": ""AeyTJd9u-0k3ihg5T1OKqc7xlfn-a5WWTwp0yeQLz03lTHotMhiuKYQGez5KgeuODtOyZNmNdcKN6WjlFuMmVlTd""
        }";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string secretMessage = "Hello world";
            string encryptedValue = Encrypt(secretMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Value:    "+encryptedValue);
            string decryptedValue = Decrypt(encryptedValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Value:    "+decryptedValue);

            string encryptedValuewithByteCode = EncryptWithByteCode(secretMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Value:    " + Decrypt(encryptedValuewithByteCode));

        }


        public static  string Encrypt(string encryptValue) {
            
            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(stringkey));
            var jwk = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JWK>(reader);
            var publicECCKey = EccKey.New(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.x), WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.y), usage: CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement);
            string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(encryptValue, publicECCKey, JweAlgorithm.ECDH_ES, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
            return token;
        }



        public static string EncryptWithByteCode(string encryptValue)
        {

            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(stringkey));
            var jwk = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JWK>(reader);
            var publicECCKey = EccKey.New(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.x), WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.y), usage: CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement);
            string token = Jose.JWT.EncodeBytes(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptValue), publicECCKey, JweAlgorithm.ECDH_ES, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
            return token;
        }


        public static string Decrypt(string encryptedValue)
        {
            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(stringkey));
            var jwk = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JWK>(reader);
            var publicECCKey = EccKey.New(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.x), WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.y), WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(jwk.d), usage: CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement);
            string token = Jose.JWT.Decode(encryptedValue, publicECCKey, JweAlgorithm.ECDH_ES, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
            return token;
        }

    }

    public class JWK
    {
        public string alg { get; set; }
        public int? created_at { get; set; }
        public string crv { get; set; }
        public int? expired_at { get; set; }
        public string kid { get; set; }
        public string kty { get; set; }
        public string use { get; set; }
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string d { get; set; }
    }
```

**Java decrypt string Generation:**

```
String encryptedFromDotNet= "eyJhbGciOiJFQ0RILUVTIiwiZW5jIjoiQTI1NkdDTSIsImVwayI6eyJrdHkiOiJFQyIsIngiOiJBWEVBdzR6MmpnRmkzRktXZ3IwNHQwS3VwOEVOeGpJaWE3aDNVQ1BZSGpwODdwMXpxMHBHVUxXVUxNaFUzOVdubERJLTFFMEl5Mzd6WmJ3LVYzQ0pURFpsIiwieSI6IkFIMUtWOWpONG9JTEpzLThGYlJmVDNVWXF3MnJDVFVZd3k5MEYwQXFFa0VZam1KOXlyekdKVC0zTGQtOUZPRUQwZV9tcE5iYlhRVk12Q25GTEQwQTdSNzIiLCJjcnYiOiJQLTUyMSJ9fQ..AXWgvsa6PwWPSS1l.UxfvMIekKvBAMbs.1n9dqJvPZQfM8v2XEkLLQg";
        String decryptedValue =  getDecryptedValue(encryptedFromDotNet);
        System.out.print(decryptedValue);

    }

public static String getDecryptedValue(String encryptedFromDotNet ) {
        try {
            String ecdhKey = "{\n"
                    + "\t\"kty\": \"EC\",\n"
                    + "\t\"d\": \"AaDyXhcUwH90OvzbYJvocSl7uYlZNRZvgj8yesGjtqUWfxmN50NIFfnBpKohNc3wkYqviScjevczATzibw0Cnlgp\",\n"
                    + "\t\"crv\": \"P-521\",\n"
                    + "\t\"x\": \"AeyTJd9u-0k3ihg5T1OKqc7xlfn-a5WWTwp0yeQLz03lTHotMhiuKYQGez5KgeuODtOyZNmNdcKN6WjlFuMmVlTd\",\n"
                    + "\t\"y\": \"AGum7Ok3MsKuMfrGtYUoeRq09oXwuO5yiMcxDjPbZglLKaZK-Z_kGt3ZcakVavLx46ieXw4agldm9qV6KmBCf6d7\"\n"
                    + "}";

            ECKey ecKey = ECKey.parse(ecdhKey);
            JWEObject jweObjectServer = EncryptedJWT.parse(encryptedFromDotNet);
            ECDHDecrypter decrypter = new ECDHDecrypter(ecKey.toECPrivateKey());
            jweObjectServer.decrypt(decrypter);
            return jweObjectServer.getPayload().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your token from dotNet is copied correctly? A JWE token has usually 5 parts, concatenated with a ".". In the end of the token I see "TUyMSJ9fQ..AXWgvsa6PwWPSS1l.UxfvMIekKvBAMbs.1n9dqJvPZQfM8v2XEkLLQg" (two dots, meaning that there is no value for part 3 of the token (that holds the nonce for the GCM decryption). This could be a good reason for the failure

Comment: @MichaelFehr: actually the empty part is #2 the encrypted key, and for ECDH-ES in 'direct' mode it should be empty: see rfc7518 4.6. (AXWgvsa6PwWPSS1l is the nonce and is 12 bytes as required for A256GCM.)

Comment: A test with JWCrypto in Python shows that an encryption with ECDH-ES, P-521 in Java can be successfully decrypted in Python, while a corresponding encryption in .NET cannot be decrypted in Python (InvalidTag). On the other hand, encryptions with ECDH-ES, P-256 in Java and .NET are successfully decrypted in Python. So the problem seems to be a bug in the .NET implementation specifically for P-521.

Comment: The bug is already known, see https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt#notes.